# C# Как добавить новый столбик в двумерный массив

Tags: массивы, c#-8.0

По заданию нужно добавить новый столбик в массив, который копирует уже существующий столбик.
Например пользователь вводит что нужно добавить 2 столбец, нужно добавить в массив новый столбик который копирует значения(числа) со второго столбца массива.
Зарание благодарен, мучаюсь с этой лабудой уже 3 сутки.
Мой кривой код:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество строк: ");
            int h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите количество столбцов: ");
            int w = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Двумерный массив: ");
            int[,] array = new int[h, w];           
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)
                {
                    array[y, x] = rnd.Next(17, 87);
                }
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(array[y, x] + "\t");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();                
                }
            Console.WriteLine("Введите столбик: ");
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] s = new int[w];

            for(int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
            {                           
                s[i] = array[i, input - 1];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Массив после обработки: ");
                for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(0); y++)
                {
                        for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)
                            {
                             Console.Write(array[y,x] + "\t" );                    
                            }
                        foreach(int x in s)
                        {                           
                            Console.Write(x);
                            break;
                        }
                    Console.WriteLine();                
                }
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Я пыталься сделать очень каряво, создал новый одномерный массив и выводил его после двумерного, трудности заключились в заполнении и выводе этого массива